# GCM errors in the logcat

Tags: android, build, firebase, dependencies, google-cloud-messaging

I'm running the official GCM sample on a Samsung S6 with 6.0.1

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

I've gone through all the steps to make it work, registering in Google Cloud Console, adding the json file, etc.

I am able to send messages with GcmSender (included in the sample) and the app on the device receives them, but:

Every time the app receives a message, there are these two errors in the logcat:

`FirebaseInstanceId  E  Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
E  Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.`

Maybe they can be ignored (the app does get the pushed messages), but they have severity = Error, what if there is a good reason for this?

What if this causes GCM to work unreliably (some sort of "exponential backoff")?

What causes them? How can I make it so that these errors do not happen?

Since the official word is that GCM will be supported going forward for existing apps -- I'd like to avoid Firebase messaging.

GCM seems easier to set up and has fewer "magical bits" all around (all the various services / registrations / tokens / APIs and what not). I just need reliable cloud driven push messaging and that's it, nothing else.

So the question is not "should I be using GCM or Firebase", I know the "correct" answer to that.

It's "when running the official GCM sample there are these errors in the logcat, what are they and how can I fix them".

Finally, the app's manifest:

https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

and the relevant bits of build.gradle:

````
```dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.2.1'
...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```
````